# Questions about Distribution Seen in a Paper

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I'm reading the following paper: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2543719 . On page 15, the author states that in a jump-diffusion process, the log jump sizes, $Y_k$, follow a binomial jump diffusion process on the interval $[-2a, a]$, where $a>0$, i.e. log jump sizes has a density

$$f(y)=\begin{cases}
-2a,  & \text{with probability } p\\
-a, & \text{with probability} 1-p
\end{cases}$$

Then the author goes on to state that

$$\mathbb{E}[e^{Y}] = pe^{-2a} + (1-p)e^{-a}.$$

I have two questions: i) I'm fairly new to the topic of Levy proceses and jump-diffusion models. Is the aforementioned distribution known in literature as a binomial jump diffusion process? Since a simple Google search doesn't seem to come up with anything like that.

ii) I am unable to see how the author derives the equation for $\mathbb{E}[e^{Y}]$. If someone can point me in the direction for how to do go about deriving it I'd be greatful.

Comment: That I know. I just integrate $\int_{-2a}^{-a}e^{u}f(u)du$, right?

Comment: It is a discrete space so the random variable $z = e^Y$ can only take 2 states. You dont need an integration but a summation.

Comment: Yes of course! Naive me... knew I was missing something obvious! Any clue about the first question?